# Regression to a space rather than a real number

Tags: regression, machine-learning, supervised-learning

I have recently been into machine learning. So far, I learned that in supervised learning, the result of regression is often a real number, for example, in linear regression, outcome y is a real number. My question is that is it possible for y to be a vector?

Comment: Certainly; it's just multivariate multiple regression instead of univariate multiple regression.

Answer (score 3):

> I learned that in supervised learning, the result of regression is often a real number

This is a false statement. There is no such "rule", regression is not limited to $\mathbb{R}$, even linear regression is defined for $\mathbb{R}^m$ for any $m \in \mathbb{N_+}$. What is even more important, even for $m=1$, the result of regression is **not a number** but rather - parameters of your model, which can be of any type and size. In case of linear regression in the form of
$$ y = Ax + b, y \in \mathbb{R^m}$$
result of this process is matrix $A$ and vector $b$.

Supervised learning is simply a learning process within which you provide your learning algorithm/system with knowledge about expected results, it is not limited to the regression nor to the any restrictions about output, it is a very wide and general concept.